# Full text search in Fossil

Tags: fossil

Are there any way to search in fossil repository for

- code
- wiki pages

Fossil's documentation claims there is a search command available in UI:
[/search](http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/help?cmd=/search) but I cannot figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In versions before 1.31, the [`search`](https://www.fossil-scm.org/fossil/help?cmd=search) command only searched check-in comments.

As of [1.31](https://www.fossil-scm.org/fossil/doc/version-1.31/www/changes.wiki), it also searches tickets, wiki, and documentation contents. But it (still) does not search source code, unless you specify your source files as searchable documentation.

As Registered User [rightly says](/questions/28647193/#28655844), searching needs to be enabled explicitly for each repository. See the help for the [srchsetup](https://www.fossil-scm.org/fossil/help?cmd=/srchsetup) page, and the [`fts-config`](https://www.fossil-scm.org/fossil/help?cmd=fts-config) command.

(The Fossil website usually runs a recent version from Fossil's own trunk branch. That's why it sometimes shows features that aren't present (yet) in the most recent binaries).

Comment: I am using 1.30. So I will wait a little bit. Would it be possible to search in the wiki that are "embedded documentation", i.o. kept with the source code?

Comment: @AntonProkofiev: yes, that’s what I meant with "documentation contents".

Comment: @AntonProkofiev: 1.31 has been released.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest from trunk, you need to enable searching in the admin section.

More specifically, please review this:
http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/help?cmd=/srchsetup

Comment: Latest version also supports `fossil grep` if that's of use.